# How to call a function from computed properties from another function in methods objet in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to call a function which is defined on the computed object of Vue.

```
<template>
                        <v-text-field
                            v-model="formatedDateInputField"
                            label="Start Date"
                            v-bind="attrs"
                            v-on="on"
                            :disabled="isLoading"
                            @click:clear="clearAndRefresh()"
                        ></v-text-field>
<template>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  computed: {
        formatedDateInputField: {
            get() {
                return this.dates && this.dates.length > 1
                    ? this.dates.join(" to ").replace(/-/g, "/")
                    : "";
            },
            set(value) {
                this.dates = value === null ? [] : value;
            }
        }
    },
```

I need to call it again to redefine the values of my text field, however when I call it from another function I will get the following console error :

- `"vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.formatedDateInputField is not a function"`
- `this.formatedDateInputField is not a function`

I tried different ways to call it, however none was sucessfull.

`(this.formatedDateInputField , this.formatedDateInputField(), this.formatedDateInputField.get() , etc... )`

I want to know what I need to do to run this computed function again in order to trigger the v-model value of my text field.

EDIT : After further inspection I guess what I am trying to do is to recompute, this is , run the computed property again.

Comment: It seems you are following [Vue computed setters](https://riptutorial.com/vue-js/example/28978/using-computed-setters-for-v-model) correctly. `formatedDateInputField` seems like a typo to me. You would write `formattedDateInputField` (two times t). If your code is an exact copy&paste, then probably not... can you provide a full demo of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to use formatedDateInputField as a function, when it's in fact a variable. Just use it as a variable.

The getter is executed when you read the variable.

```js
console.log(this.formatedDateInputField)
```

And the setter when you try to overwrite it.

```js
this.formatedDateInputField = '2022-02-02'
```